# Confidence interval of mean difference of matched samples with repetitions

Tags: confidence-interval, repeated-measures

I have a dataset consisting of localisation ratings $x_{s,c}^{(r)}$, where $S$ subjects (index $s$) had to rate $C$ different conditions (index $c$). Each condition was presented to each subject $R$ times (index $r$) resulting in $RC$ ratings per subject. The order of presentation was randomized for each subject. Let

$$\bar x_{s,c} = \frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^{R} x_{s,c}^{(r)} $$

be the mean rating of a subject $s$ for a certain condition $c$ and

$$d_{s,c_1,c_2} = \bar x_{s,c_1} - \bar x_{s,c_2}$$

be the difference of the means for two conditions $c_1$ and $c_2$ and the same subject. How do I calculate the confidence interval of the mean difference $\mu_d$ among all subjects, which corresponds to the statistic

$$\bar d_{c_1,c_2} = \frac{1}{S} \sum_{s=1}^{S} d_{s,c_1,c_2}\,?$$

Since the differences are calculated with respect to the same subject, I thought this problem somehow connects to confidence intervals for matched samples, e.g., in the tutorial [*Confidence Intervals for Matched Samples, Continuous Outcome*](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_Confidence_Intervals/BS704_Confidence_Intervals6.html) on the Boston University School of Public Health's website. However, the explanations do not cover the repetitions. How do I incorporate them? If there is a solution, what kind of assumptions does it make about the underlying distributions?